# What is this grilling utensil with two wire mesh panels?

Tags: equipment, grilling, barbecue, utensils

I want to buy this cooking utensil but have no idea what it is called and where i can buy one from. I think it is mainly used on barbeques. Ive tried googling and had no luck. I'll try describing it as best as i can.

It has 2 large rectangular flat metal wire mesh panels which fold onto one another like a clam when you close them. You can place meat in between the wire mesh  and clasp the handles together to hold the meat firmly between the 2 meshes. You can then cook the meat over a flame and flip the utensil to cook the other side of the meat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A [grill basket](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=3742141) perhaps?

I've no luck finding the term for your specific description, but that seems to be an umbrella term for utensils that basically hold something so you can more easily grill it.

Comment: Yes, number 4 on the linked page is what sprang to mind when I read the description...

Comment: bingo! no 4 it is.

Answer (score 5):

In South Africa we are barbecue (we call it "braai") nuts and we use these utensils all the time. In Afrikaans (my first language) we call them a "toeklap rooster" which Google translates as a slamming grid which I would say is better translated as a slamming grill or folding grill or just plainly a braai grill. Here you can buy them in just about any grocery, hardware or any other store that sells any kinds of barbecue utensils. Such as this: [Braai Grill](http://www.pricecheck.co.za/offers/14338714/HotRods+Barracuda+Braai+Grill+With+Tongs+%26+Bag/)

Here in SA everyone who speaks English knows the term "toeklap rooster," so I've never actually wondered about the proper English term. @janeylicious's term "grill basket" is nifty and I'm curious to know what the rest of the world's official definition of this is.

Comment: +1 braai grid, or braai grill - costs about US$10.

Answer (score 1):

Although its intended use is for fish a '[fish grill](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/sol/shop/home_and_garden/sainsburyslivingmagazine/121052309_sainsburys_barbeque_fish_grill.html?CAWELAID=867854294)' like this would probably be sufficient for holding meat, the metal is quite flexible meaning you can put quite thick pieces of meat in it. These seem quite a bit cheaper then a grill basket as they are smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You mean one of [these](http://www.outsetinc.com/item/QC71)?

[image: uUtset products Grill Basket]

If so, you can find out where to buy it [here](http://www.outsetinc.com/page/whereToBuy).

Comment: I was going to update your answer to include the name of the utensil for your first link's text but it's now throwing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Another word for it, I guess, would be [grid iron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gridiron_%28cooking%29). I found it through swedish "halster", using google translate, I found grid iron.